# Post new comment to a Status via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I'm having a status_id and try to post a new comment to:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/STATUS_ID/comments {message: "text" }
```

I get the result

```
{
 "error": {
   "message": "(#200) Cannot access object_id: 10150593515092107", 
   "type": "OAuthException", 
   "code": 200
  }
}
```

I can do the same POST for /likes and it works.

If I add a comment to a Photo it also works. I can then use the object_id of a photo but no such field exists on a status.

Comment: Is it only that specific post which is failing? It could be a database problem on Facebook's side - can you access that post on the regular facebook.com interface?
Also, are you able to like or post comments to that status? a GET request to /STATUS_ID should return the details of the status, which will include details on whether or not your access_token's user can interact with that status - privacy settings may allow you to see a status but not to comment on it

Comment: It's all statuses. I can get the status fine. I'm also able to POST a new like (but not a commment). I'm testing in the Graph API explorer now. But when i POST to XXXX/comments { message: "my message" } I get the error above.

Comment: How exactly are you POSTing the request? Perhaps you may want to show your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After two days of struggle i found the answer, at least for regular posts.

Every `object_id` of a post on facebook consists from two parts: `[author id]_[post id]` you can see it clearly in the permalink: `https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=[post id]&id=[author id]`

so when you use the full id it seems to work!

Now the real question is why isn't it propertly documented by facebook?!? and to who can I write an angry letter for wasting my time.

it still doesn't work for videos or photos for example because I don't know what is the proper ID's for them and it isn't written anywhere. So if you succeed please let me know.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I was using the FB API to pull in a users news feed. Some items had an `ID` and others had an `object_ID`. I ended up checking for `object_ID`, and using that to then post a comment. If not `object_ID` existed, I split the `ID` by the underscore and used the latter part. This seems to help but the comments still fail on some posts, I'm yet to find out which kind of posts yet. I'll put it down to lack of documentation.

Comment: Thanks! On photos you can get the object_id if you use fql (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/). This is a query you can run in the Graph Explorer to get all photos from ALL albums from a specific user. You can tweak it as you want: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"photos":"SELECT object_id, pid, aid, owner, link FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=USER_ID_HERE)"}

Answer (score 0):

here is a practical solution I use knowing that for some objects the userid is needed and for some it is not (for comments and likes).

```
    var message = 'WHATEVER MESSAGE';

FB.api('/'+object_id+'/comments','post',{
    message:message
},function(r){
    if (!r || r.error) {
        // if it fails,send it back with the fbid on it
        FB.api('/'+fbme.id+'_'+object_id+'/comments','post',{
            message:message
        },function(r){
            if (!r || r.error) {
                //  if it fails again send back to server side for failure recording 
                $.post("actions.php",{
                    req:'badPost',
                    oid:object_id
                },function(n){

                });

            }
        });             
    } 
});
```

this works for me