# Cannot post comment with Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am trying to post a comment to a stream object using the Facebook API. Here is my code:

```
$this->facebook->api('/' . $postID . '/comments', 'post', array(
    'message' => 'Hello world!'
));
```

I have set the `publish_stream` permission like so:

```
<fb:login-button scope="email, read_stream, publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

However, the comment is not working. I am getting OAuthException:

`(#200) Cannot access object_id: 3427843256389`

I have the correct permission, and the correct post ID. I can't work out for the life of me why it won't let me access the object. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the graph api explorer tool to see if you can do it there.  You might be able to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Also, try doing an HTTP GET command to `/3427843256389`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this just reconfirms what I already know: Here's the error I'm getting: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Cannot access object_id: 238537006239302", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}

Comment: The GET works. It retrieves the comments already on the post. I just can't POST.

Comment: Is it only on that one ID, or for any post?

Comment: I've been playing around some more - it's only on certain IDs. I don't understand why, perhaps someone can explain? I posted a status on my own account and I can't get it to comment on that, but it will comment on some other status.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly opposite what I would expect.  In the app settings you can create a test account or two, and try the same thing with those accounts to see if this is always the case with you app.

Comment: I am retrieving the user's news feed, and using the ID given from there to comment on objects. However, I think I may have noticed the problem. Sometimes, Facebook will provide a story with an `object_id`, and other times, it will only get an `id`. If I use `object_id` where it is provided, and `id` (split the underscore, use the second half) where it is not, the comment works most of the time. Still testing. Will come back to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Oliver Joseph Ash for your last comment.. thanks to you i tried and succeeded to add comment to a regular post (not a video or photo yet though..) see my full answer in [Post new comment to a Status via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377922/post-new-comment-to-a-status-via-api)